# Xcode and checking for code convention

Tags: objective-c, xcode, coding-style

How can I configure xcode to check my source code if it respects standard apple (or github) objective c code convention?

If something does not match - would be nice to get some kind of warning...

thanks

Comment: why downvoting the question?

Answer (score 12):

I've met the followings links:

- [ClangFormat-Xcode](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode) - XCode plugin, based on [ClangFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)
- **[ocstyle](https://github.com/Cue/ocstyle)** - code-style checker, can be used on Continous Integration server
- **[StrictCode](http://strictcodeapp.com/)** - Source code formatter for Mac. that costs 20$
- **[Objective-Clean](http://objclean.com/index.php)**

These are other links & references you may find interesting:

1. http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/
2. http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/features.php
3. https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode